# conflict when cross compile octeon with mips64

Tags: cross-compiling, mips64

I use buildroot201802 for cross compile tool.
when I compile with `mips64el-linux-gcc *.c -march=octeon -mips64`

***here is what I got:***

[image]

but I do have target kernel modules file:quicksec.ko which is octeon with mips64..
I'm wondering how to solve it.

Comment: Please put in the error as text. People will not follow some link to see an image.

Comment: is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

remove `-mips64`  from gcc invokation.  Instead add `-mabi=64`  to specify the ABI.

The machine arcitecture spec  `-march=octeon`   automatically selects mips64r2, so you don't need to attempt to specify that.

Besides, the most common OCTEON platforms use OCTEON in big-endian mode. So unless you know what you are doing, and verified from ELF headers the Endina mode,  instead of `mips64el-linux-gcc` you should be using the big-Endian compiler  `mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc`.   But this is probably a different question / thread.

-Irfan /Paxym

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But what I wanna to compile is mip64 not mips64r2.
Besides,I have no idea where to get mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc..It seems like buildroot doesn't support this.